# Pass data between fragments with Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I read a lot of discussion about that, and someone suggests to use Bundle to pass data between two fragments in the same activity...I tried some come, but it didn't worked.
I have 2 fragments in my `GroupDetailActivity`. The paymentFragment, which download data from a database and show them in a listView, and the fragment `FragmentReport`, which displays a report of the payments.
So, after the paymentFragment get the data, I need to pass some of them to the second fragment. That's my code:

PaymentFragment:

```
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
final FragmentReport fragment = new FragmentReport();

// This is inside the onCreateView, where I get the the data from the db and show them in a listview
bundle.putInt("num_of_pay", cont);
Log.v("cont", String.valueOf(cont)); // it display the correct number of person
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment);
```

Then, in my FragmentReport, inside the `OnCreateView`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_fragment,container,false);
    numberOfPaymentTV = rootView.findViewById(R.id.n_payment_tv);

    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    if (args != null){
        numberOfPaymentTV.setText(args.getInt("num_of_pay"));
        Log.v("totalPayment", String.valueOf(args.getInt("num_of_pay"))); // I don't get any log, maybe this fragment doesn't receive the data
    }

    return rootView;
}
}
```

I don't get any error, but the textView doesn't show the "cont" value.
Maybe I could use sharedPreferences? Is it possibile achieve that with Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You can get args in `onCreate()` function.

```
private Bundle bundle;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView))
            .setText(String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("KEY")));

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.bundle = getArguments();
}
```

Comment: I'll try it later..but the data that I get are from firebase, so they took at least 1 second to appear on the screen. Will it work? The on create method start when I open the activity, but the data aren't downloaded yet...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the String.valueOf(int) when setting an int as text in a TextView:

```
numberOfPaymentTV.setText(String.valueOf(getArguments().getInt("num_of_pay"))
```